# Laravel 'Whoops, something went wrong'

Tags: laravel

I've created a Laravel booking application that is currently being used in schools. When I test the live (production) version of the website on my own machine, the application works fine.

However, some schools are reporting that they are not even able to see the initial login screen, and are getting the Laravel 'Whoops, something went wrong' screen. I can confirm that the school firewall is not causing the issue, and that the website has worked ok in the past.

What reasons could there be for the same code to work on my machine but not on the live version? So far I have tried resetting the browser cache, and also flushed the DNS but to no avail...

Any suggestion are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Start by checking your error logs. Otherwise, nobody will be able to give you a solution to your problem.

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that I have checked the logs, and one of the errors is a missing view. But the view is not missing, and works fine on my machine (as well as my colleagues). It's as if the application on their machine is pointing to an old version of the application where the view was missing at one time...

Comment: Also check folder permissions.

Comment: Check folder permissions (mainly storage and public), run `composer update`, check owner of files and folders.

Comment: It is not that the views are missing, but that the cache views cannot be created. I'm positive the problem is in the folder permissions, specifically in the storage/framework/views folder

Answer (score 0):

It seems like folder permissions problem.
As the error is not shown, nobody can really help you..
What I suggest, is first to check the log file (`storage/logs/laravel***.log`).
There you should be able normally to see the problem and then you can fix it.
Another solution, in your ".env" file, switch from production to development mode, so you can be able to see the exception.

Comment: Dude, that is not an answer, rather a comment made from all the comments already done.

Answer (score 0):

Check capitialization on the view name. I've had issues where everything works fine locally, but then get not found issues when live as the server behaves differently and is case sensitive.